# Get Part of String

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am not good at Regular expression and couldn't find an easy way for this problem.

i have an expression like:

`TR_NN_Expression`

Where NN is a number of 2 digits, and Expression can contain '_', so i can't use split for this. I would like to get the Expression. Any help would be greater appreciated.

Comment: Woah, I totally missed that Apple shipped a regex class with Lion.

Comment: Is Expression always going to be last element?

Comment: Yes Expression is the last element

Comment: zneak: so how can i get the expression?

Comment: Um, are you using Javascript or Cocoa? I see the tags on your question changed.

Comment: Zneak; javascript i have hard time understanding your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
TR_[0-9]{2}_(.*)
```

The part you want will be in the capturing group. Example usage:

```
> s = 'TR_01_My#@34_Expresion'
"TR_01_My#@34_Expresion"
> s.match(/TR_[0-9]{2}_(.*)/)[1]
"My#@34_Expresion"
```

Comment: how do you get the (.*)? is javascript let say i have my expression in 
var my txt = 'TR_01_My#@34_Expresion';.

Answer (score 1):

I always use and recommend this tool, It makes our life to easier,

[Interactive multi-language regular expression generator](http://txt2re.com/)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is of fixed length and you know that the strings are of the correct format you can just use `substring` to accomplish this.

```
"TR_42_some_expression_here".substring(6) // yields "some_expression_here"
```

If you have a more complicated situation, regular expressions may be appropriate. The exact expression depends on what you wish to capture.

Comment: TR can be longer, so i couldn't use the substring

Comment: @FrenchiInLa: What do you mean by "TR can be longer"? Can you be more specific about what the start of the string is?

Comment: TR can be AAAA, is always letter usually 2 but can be more than e letters

Comment: @FrenchiInLa: You'll have to be more explicit about the format of the string for us to be able to help. The regular expression Mark provided above also assumes that you have the literal string "TR_", followed by two digits, followed by another underscore, and then the expression.